# Umbraco Development Setup Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment, umbraco

I am a new developer for Umbraco. I am having problem setting up my Visual Studio 2010 as a developer platform for umbraco 4.5.x with TFS and between remote teams.

My current setup is to open the whole umbraco site in Visual studio and tideup with TFS. Obeviusly this means that some of the files and folders gets locked up when commiting to Source control. Problem is this causes the problem when running umbraco as umbraco tried to write to certain files.

Any idea what type of typical setup would be like for VS 2010 and umbraco?

thanks,
Preyash

Comment: Umbraco 5 is dead should you remove your edit?

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem =)

EDIT: Link updated

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/codegarden-2009/open-space-minutes/working-in-visual-studio-when-developing-umbraco-solutions

I made a VS2010 umbraco project template, that configures the commands used to copy files to the umbraco folder on build, like described in the above link.

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/visual-studio-2010-project-template

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already seen the link. I dont want to use the XCopy command for this. I am looking something like msbuild.

Comment: Any particular reason?
Im in the middle of creating a umbraco template for vs2010, and im using xcopy, but i may change that if theres a better way =)
Have you seen this blogpost? http://cjgiddings.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/setting-up-umbraco-correctly-with-msbuild/

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use TFS as your version control?

We have used **Mercurial** and **Visual svn server** as version controls in our projects.

In this i feel Mercurial as more comfortable for Umbraco projects.

Comment: No its not mandatory to use TFS. You can use any version control system. The basic idea is to know which files to be included in the version control because umbraco generates files from the backoffice which could create problems in version control.

Comment: @Preyash : i think the changes will occur continuously in custom dlls and also in temp folder i think. So when you are using any version control it is better to add the **custom dlls** and **TEMP** folder as a whole to **ignore list**.